# tomcat ssl redirect loop

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

My application use ssl in tomcat, and run fine when I use port 8080, when I access http://localhost:8080, it redirect to https://localhost:8443.

But when I use a non 8080 port (8081,8082, etc) and I access http://localhost:8081 (or http://localhost:8082, etc), it does a infinite redirect loop to http://localhost:8081 (or http://localhost:8082, etc)

here my server.xml with 8080

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />


            <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keyAlias="key" keystoreFile="webapps/ROOT/META-INF/my.keystore" keystorePass="pass" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>   


    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">


      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

and here my server.xml with 8081

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />


            <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keyAlias="key" keystoreFile="webapps/ROOT/META-INF/my.keystore" keystorePass="pass" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>   


    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">


      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Can anyone help me?

I'm using tomcat 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing to try is to forcibly enable HTTPS for all the apps, in the default web.xml (it should be in tomcat/conf folder next to server.xml),
by adding the following to it:

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
                    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

*Note:* The below applies to the Tomcat instances with ARP enabled (i.e. most Linux-based installations), but as OP is running a windows-based Tomcat, with the ARP connector already disabled (or not available), it does not apply to him.

---

Not sure on why do you get a redirect loop, but an apparent problem with your configuration is that you have the [APR](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html) (native) SSL connector enabled, which does not really work with "keystoreFile", so you should be getting error messages like that in your logs:

```
java.lang.Exception: Connector attribute SSLCertificateFile must be defined when using SSL with APR
```

and SSL should not function for you at all, regardless of a port number used.

And easiest way to defeat it, is to comment out the APR listener:

```
<!-- <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" /> -->
```

to make Tomcat use JSSE connector implementation instead.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm don't getting any error in the logs neither using port 8080 nor using port 8081. My application works fine with the ssl in port 8080. But I'm tested with the APR listener commented out too, and no changes, no errors and redirect loop using port 8081. I'm using Tomcat 6.

Comment: Ok, I see, so probably you just don't have ARP installed in the first case.

Which OS/exact version of Tomcat are you running ?
Your config looks like a Tomcat 6 (but I might be wrong on that).
I've tried running Tomcat 6 (via official Docker image), with your config, and aside I had to disable ARP (which was turned on by default for me), it worked just fine (i.e. no redirection loop).

Comment: Also do you have anything sitting in front of your Tomcat instance (Nginx e.t.c.) ?

Comment: No, I'm dont using nothing in front of Tomcat. I tested in Windows 10 and Windows server 2012, that same problem in both. Corret redirect in Port 8080 , and loop redirect in Port 8081. My application use spring mvc

Comment: Can you confirm that trying to access some other file or app, does result in a redirect loop too (i.e. this is not your spring  app specific) ?

You can try to go to http://localhost:8081/index.html (Tomcat index page, if you have not removed it), or http://localhost:8081/manager/status (if you have Tomcat Manager app installed).

Also when you go directly to :8443, does it still work for you (with 8081 as the HTTP port) ?

Comment: Yes, I can access http://localhost:8081/index.html, http://localhost:8081/manager/status and directly https://localhost:8443

Comment: Ok, it looks like the problem is in the Spring app (i.e. it does the redirect itself), try to force-enable HTTPS for all the web apps (see my update),  and see if it helps.

Comment: can you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875498/apache-mod-proxy-tomcat-remove-8443 @zeppelin