# apache mod_proxy tomcat remove 8443

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, mod-proxy, server.xml

I put apache in front of tomcat using mod_proxy. The apache is listening on port 80, and when I access from www.example.com the apache redirect to port 8080 wich tomcat is listening, and tomcat redirect to port 8443. The problem is the address bar show https://www.example.com:8443.

How I remove the :8443 from the address bar?

Apache virtualhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Tomcat server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />

            <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keyAlias="key" keystoreFile="webapps/ROOT/META-INF/my.keystore" keystorePass="pass" maxThreads="150" port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>   

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

I'm using Tomcat 6, Apache 2.4 and Windows Server 2012

**EDIT**

virtualhost

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
 ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost> 

 <VirtualHost _default_:443> 
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/example.key"
  SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/www_example_com.crt"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/www_example_com.ca-bundle"
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

server.xml

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />         

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://serverfault.com/questions/505316/ssl-setup-with-apache-in-front-of-tomcat. (Basically you are trying to setup an HTTP-only reverse proxy in front of HTTPS enabled tomcat).

Comment: I adjusted like indicated in the link http://serverfault.com/questions/505316/ssl-setup-with-apache-in-front-of-tomcat (look my EDIT). Works fine when I use the default tomcat app, but when I use my spring app I get a wrong redirect error

Comment: Do you "ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443" or "http://localhost:8080" ?

Comment: localhost:8080.

Comment: Try `https://localhost:8443` instead

Comment: Withhttps://localhost:8443 I get this error: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8443 (localhost) failed

Comment: Hmm, can you connect to http://localhost:8443 with a browser ? If yes, does it show certificate as valid ?

Comment: No, I can't connect to localhost:8443. After my edit only Apache has a certificate, Tomcat is listening only in port 8080. Should I enable ssl in tomcat and use the same certificate?

Comment: Ok, but can you connect on http:// localhost:8080 ? or you get the redirect error too ?

Comment: When I connect to  http:// localhost:8080, it redirect to https://localhost:8443/ and don't open

Comment: My application works on a server managed by third part, I can see the tomcat server.xml and web.xml, and they are like default, so the settings that allow my app work are in apache, but I can't see the apache files.

Comment: I solved it using ajp connector instead http. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome ! It's good to hear that you have solved it